# Eigenvalue-eigenvector advance question

Tags: matrices

Anyone have some hint of how to do this question :) ?, a small $10 iTunes gift card will give away who help me to understand the question. 
thanks guy ;) 
[image]

Comment: $A$ is similar ($A = P^{-1}DP$) to diagonal matrix $D$ with $\lambda_j$ down the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

(a) We know that $A$ is a square $N\times N$ matrix and since the matrix $A$ consist of eigenvectors, the matrix is linearly independent and hench diagonalizable. The Determinant of $A$ is therefor the product of the diagonal (the eigenvalues). i.e.$$\det A=\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3\cdots\lambda_N$$

(b) Since $A$ and $\lambda I$ are both diagonal, then $(A-\lambda I)$ is diagonal. Then 
$$\det (A-\lambda I)=(\lambda_1-\lambda)(\lambda_2-\lambda)(\lambda_3-\lambda)\cdots(\lambda_N-\lambda)$$
Expanding and rearranging the terms we have
$$\text{for }N=2\implies\lambda^2\underline{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)\lambda}+\lambda_1\lambda2=0$$
$$\text{for }N=3\implies-\lambda^3\underline{+(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3)\lambda^2}-(\lambda_1\lambda_2+\lambda_1\lambda_3+\lambda_2\lambda3)\lambda+\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3=0$$
$$\vdots$$
The coefficients $a_{N-1}$ of the $\lambda_{N-1}$ term is therefor given by
$$a_{N-1}=(-1)^{N-1}(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\cdots+\lambda_N)$$